# Null checks for a complex dereference chain in Java 8

Tags: java-8, nullpointerexception, option-type

So I have a class generated by some contract (so no modifications allowed) with multiple data layers, I get it through soap request and then in my backend I have something like this:

```
value = bigRequest.getData().getSamples().get(0).getValuableData().getValue()
```

and in every dereference in that chain I can have null result. Class itself has no logic, just pure data with accessors, but nonetheless. I'm kinda sick of thought to make an ugly boilerplate of not-null checks for every single dereference, so I'm thinking of the best practice here:

1. Actually make the ugly boilerplate (either with ifs or with asserts). I assume that its what I've got to do, but I have faint hopes.
2. Do some Optional magic. But with no access to modify the source it'll probably be even uglier.
3. Catch the NPE. It's ugly in its heart, but in this particular case I feel it's the best option, just because it's part of the logic, either I have that value or not. But catching NPE makes me shiver.
4. Something I can't see by myself now.

I'm actually feel myself a little bit uncomfortable with this question cause I feel that NPE theme is explored to the bones, but I had no success in search.

Comment: I don't think a chain of `map` looks that ugly: `Optional.ofNullable(bigRequest).map(RequestCls::getData).map(DataCls::getSamples).map(samples -> samples.get(0)).map(SampleCls::getValuableData).map(ValDataCls::getValue)`

Comment: @andrew-vershinin it's beautiful nevertheless it doesn't work =) But as of this moment I'm not sure if this is collection-specific. So, I have null at `map(DataCls::getSamples)`, and next map leads to IndexOutOfBoundsException, so it's probably working at whole, but needs special logic for lists. I need my morning dose of caffeine then I can be more objective.

Comment: Well of course, you need to check if the collection is not empty, but how it works is that mapping a `null` won't produce an error, but another empty `Optional`, so you need to fix only that part of the chain.

Comment: 5. Stop the behavior of returning `null`.

Comment: @AndrewVershinin, adding .filter(samples -> samples.size() > 0) worked as well. Add this as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: @Holger the main thing is exactly about unavailability to modify the base class. Obviously there's a huge field to refactor if I could, but I have a carved in stone class to unmarshal from xml so I have access only to algorithms on receiveing end.

Comment: Another option is to rewrite some parts of your code in other JVM languages like Kotlin or Groovy that have null-safe operator '?'. For example in Kotlin your code would look like `bigRequest.getData()?.getSamples()?.getOrNull(0)?.getValuableData()?.getValue()` which is completely null-safe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with both of you that Andrew Vershinin’s suggestion is the best we can do here and thus deserves to be posted as an answer.

```
nullableValue = Optional.ofNullable(bigRequest)
        .map(RequestCls::getData)
        .map(DataCls::getSamples)
        .filter(samples -> ! samples.isEmpty())
        .map(samples -> samples.get(0))
        .map(SampleCls::getValuableData)
        .map(ValDataCls::getValue)
        .orElse(null);
```

You will need to substitute the right class or interface names in the method references (or you may rewrite as lambdas if you prefer). Edit: If `bigRequest` itself cannot be `null`, the first method call should be just `Optional.of(bigRequest)`.

It’s not the primarily intended use of `Optional`, but I find it OK. And better than items 1. and 3. (and 4.) from your question.

Comment: The only caveat is memory overhead due `Optional` instance creation inside every `Optional#map` invocation.